# Can I use a string variable to initialize a class in PHP?

Tags: php

I'd like to use a string variable to initialize an object. Is something like this possible?

```
$class = "MyClass";
$x = new $class();
return $x;
```

Edit: Ha, so when I tried to test this and it didn't work I had a syntax error somewhere else in my script. Apparently this works just fine. Neat.

Comment: Why don't you try it and see?

Comment: Yes it is possible!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. Its possible in PHP.

```
$className = 'MyClass';
$object = new $className;
```

Attaching PHP documentation snippet on new operator
[image]

Comment: Why need to remove bracket ! I want to know !

Comment: Actually it works with Brackets as well, updated the answer.